# Makefile - using math in a loop

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to make a loop. I would like to use the values:
10, 20, 30, 40, 50..

I managed to get the function to print out 1,2,3,4,5:

```
main:
    for i in `seq 1 5`; do \
        echo $$i; \
    done;
```

But somehow simple mathmatics doesn't work. This fails:

```
main:
    for i in `seq 1 5`; do \
        echo $$i*10; \
    done;
```

I've also tried performing math inside $ symbols and vrackets without any luck. Would love your input on this.

Comment: If you want to do simple math in a POSIX shell you can use `expr`: change your `echo` to `expr $$i \* 10` (don't forget to quote the `*` else the shell will glob expand it, and you must put whitespace around every argument, you can't run them together as you did above).

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by using SHELL on first line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
main:
    for i in `seq 1 5`; do \
        echo $$(( $$i*10 )); \
    done;
```